# How can I intercept a request to check authorization before the view class instantiation occurs in a Vaadin 14 web app?

Tags: java, annotations, authorization, vaadin, shiro

I'm trying to integrate [Apache Shiro's Annotation-based Authorization](https://shiro.apache.org/authorization.html#Authorization-AnnotationbasedAuthorization) (authz) into a Vaadin 14 web app. I've looked into some publicly available solutions regarding this topic:

- [ILAY - authorization for Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/ilay---authorization-for-vaadin/1.0.0);
- [Secure Router Navigation](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/setting-up-spring-security#_secure_router_navigation) (from the Setting up Spring Security for Vaadin applications tutorial).

They all seem to use the same solution, setup a [`VaadinServiceInitListener`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-service-init-listener.html) to add a [`BeforeEnterEvent`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle.html#beforeenterevent) listener where all the authz logic must be implemented.

**I thinks one problem arises with this kind of solution:**

> Since Vaadin views are built from the class constructor, the target view class as already been instantiated when reaching the `BeforeEnterEvent` authz validation, which means that the view is processed whether or not the requester has authorization to access it.

How can I intercept the requests before the `View` classes are instantiated so I can do a proper authz check using Shiro's annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Vaadin doesn't offer "any good way of intercepting navigation requests before the navigation target class is instantiated", I took the long and winding road and came up with a **solution based on a custom `Interceptor`**. This allowed me to short circuit the requests before the view class instantiation occurs, with the following visible results:

- Pros:

  - **Security** - code doesn't get executed by users not authorized to do so;
  - **Performance** - since I perform the authz verification earlier, all the overhead of running unnecessary code is gone.
- Cons:

  - The need to use an additional annotation. It would be great to have a solution to integrate seamlessly with the existing Shiro annotations, any improvements are welcomed.

### The solution

Add a new **`@ShiroSecured`annotation** to bind with the interceptor:

```java
package misc.app.security;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;


@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@InterceptorBinding
public @interface ShiroSecured { }
```

Add a **`ShiroSecuredInterceptor`** and bind it to the previously defined custom annotation. Make sure to have a method annotated with [`@AroundConstruct`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/interceptor/AroundConstruct.html) so the calls to the constructor of classes annotated with `@ShiroSecured` get intercepted:

```java
package misc.app.security;

import javax.interceptor.AroundConstruct;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;


/**
 * An interceptor for declarative security checks using the annotations from the 
 * {@code org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation} package.
 *
 */
@ShiroSecured @Interceptor
public class ShiroSecuredInterceptor extends AnnotationsAuthorizingConstructorInterceptor {

    @AroundConstruct
    public Object checkAuthorization(final InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        assertAuthorized(new InvocationContextToConstructorInvocationConverter(ic));

        return ic.proceed();
    }

    private static class InvocationContextToConstructorInvocationConverter implements ConstructorInvocation {

        private final InvocationContext context;


        public InvocationContextToConstructorInvocationConverter(InvocationContext ic) {
            context = ic;
        }

        @Override
        public Object proceed() throws Throwable {
            return context.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public Class getClazz() {
            return context.getConstructor().getDeclaringClass();
        }
    }   
}
```

Register the interceptor in `beans.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans bean-discovery-mode="all" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">

    <interceptors>
        <class>misc.app.security.ShiroSecuredInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

That summarizes the main pieces of the solution. The following screenshot lists all the class files I implemented in order to make it work. Basically I had to **duplicate part of [Shiro's logic related to `MethodInvocation`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/f782eb1084df73eff3e2ac0f9780cb4a4f429041/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authz/aop) to make it work for `ConstructorInvocation`**. The two `Error` classes are implementation of [Vaadin's Router Exception Handling](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-exception-handling.html) for Shiro's [`AuthorizationException`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/f782eb1084df73eff3e2ac0f9780cb4a4f429041/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authz/AuthorizationException.java) and [`UnauthenticatedException`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/f782eb1084df73eff3e2ac0f9780cb4a4f429041/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authz/UnauthenticatedException.java), thrown when the authz validation fails.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is currently not any good way of intercepting navigation requests before the navigation target class is instantiated.

As a general workaround, you should ensure that you're not doing anything that can have security implications in the constructor of the class but instead using methods such `onAttach` since they will be called only after the `BeforeEnterEvent` has been dispatched and only if no listener prevented the navigation.

This problem was recently addressed in the core framework through [issue #4595](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4595). It has not yet been decided in which version of Vaadin the changes will be introduced because of the way they can impact backwards compatibility in some cases.

Comment: Hey @Leif, Thanks for the quick answer, since I didn't find "any good way of intercepting navigation requests before the navigation target class is instantiated" in Vaadin 14 either, I took a different approach and came up with a solution explained in a new answer to this question. Make sure to take a look and comment, all feedback is welcome.